# Two black strips on my wallpaper after uninstalling 'Starter Background Changer' - Why is this?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

About a week ago I downloaded starter background changer but soon uninstalled it. When I uninstalled the program my desktop picture went back to default which was fine except that the picture didn't fit the screen exactly. It had two black stripes at either side of the picture. This is very annoying and bothersome and I've tried everything!

I tried right clicking on an empty space on my desktop and going into screen resolution, rotate, panel fit, anything you can dream! Is there any way I can get it normal again?

Comment: The user's reverting back from the changed desktop background; please don't vote to close.  I'll let mine expire.

Answer (score 3):

Try right click on the desktop, choose Personalize, then click on the Desktop Background near the bottom, and check the Picture Position.  It may now be Center, try changing it to Fill or Stretch.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too.
I installed it again. I discovered that when I had tried out the program I also I had changed the way the wallpaper was displayed to "adjust" (so that the picture would show complete on the screen). I changed it to the regular stretched layout, selecting the standard Starter blue wallpaper. Then I uninstalled the program again. This solved the problem.
I hope it helps.